# Example for creating tiles from image for use in mapbox-(gl)-js

Tags: tiles, mapbox, gdal2tiles, mapbox-gl

I'm facing weird random tile selection issues (like floating precision causes a wrong tile to load) when using some existing static tile data with mapbox-gl-js.

I'm therefore searching for an example or tutorial for creating a tile set for usage with mapbox-(gl)-js. It seems to be some kind of implementation specific issue that my tile set doesn't work, even though it should be the right projection.

Comment: Can you share some code or a live example? At very least a link to your tileset would be helpful to diagnose here.

Comment: Hey Lyzi, thanks for your feedback. Here is a hacked demo: http://update.deepmap.de/maptest2/tiles.html